# Windows Search OCR plugin/extension

Tags: windows, pdf, search, plugins, ocr

Is there any plugin or solution available to let **Windows Search** index text in graphic pages embedded into pdf files.

Something like the amazing **Omnipage OCR plugin** which was available for Google Desktop, I used with WinXP?

Answer (score 2):

> Microsoft® offers effective instruments to organize enterprise search on different levels, from centralized content storage to desktop. Microsoft Office SharePoint Server has powerful search capabilities in SharePoint document libraries and folders; Windows Search is helpful in finding files on desktop computers.
>
> [**ABBYY Recognition Server IFilter**](http://www.abbyy.com/recognition_server/OCR_IFilter_for_Microsoft/) is a powerful add-on to these enterprise search engines – enabling them to search through the full content of image documents. Normally enterprise search engines can index full text only in document file formats like HTML, RTF, DOC, XLS, etc. In reality, a lot of important information is contained in image files such as JPEGs, PDFs and TIFFs – and as such remains invisible for conventional search engines. Scanned and photographed documents, invoices, letters, contracts – all these documents can be retrieved only using the file name, not the actual content of the document. To extend full-text search to image documents and leave no important knowledge undiscovered, OCR IFilter functionality is a must.
>
> ABBYY Recognition Server with its OCR IFilter component is exactly the right solution: it “unlocks” the content of image documents by means of OCR and makes it available for indexing by SharePoint Server and Microsoft Search. With ABBYY Recognition Server IFilter, document search becomes truly all encompassing.

[image: 1]

The following article might also be of interest to you: [OCR’ing all of the PDF files in a SharePoint Document Library using PowerShell and Solid PDF Tools](http://bable.cybermarshall.com/2009/05/27/ocring-all-of-the-pdf-files-in-a-sharepoint-document-library-using-powershell-and-solid-pdf-tools/) (I know it mentions SharePoint, but there's no reason you can't run the PowerShell code on your local machine).